# What is the formula or algorithm used in libgdx delta time?

Tags: libgdx, timestep

I'm studying time stepping algorithm and I need to know how delta time works in libgdx, because I think delta time uses some kind of time stepping algorithm.

Comment: Did you take a look at the [source](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx)?

Answer (score 1):

libgdx seems, [based on the source](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/9763e5ce6cd4bb5ce9a533f1fa449353cebe0dfb/backends/gdx-backend-moe/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/iosmoe/IOSGraphics.java#L236), to compute delta time with some variant of

```
long time = System.nanoTime();
deltaTime = (time - lastFrameTime) / 1000000000.0f;
lastFrameTime = time;
```

for every back-end renderer implementation. This is usually done when the renderer is ticked (the view is drawn, effectively). There doesn't appear to be any time-stepping going on.